# How to access container hostname from host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running docker containers from MaxOS(docker for mac). I have setup a bridge network for these containers. Each of them has its own hostname and they can connect to each other through the hostname. Now I want to connect to these containers from my host os which is Mac by their hostname. How can I do that? I only know that I can bind port number to my host os but I don't know how to access these containers by their hostname.

I know that I can attach the container by docker command like below:

```
docker exec -it $INSTANCE_NAME /bin/bash
```

But I want to access it through network.